# elisp function to change string case from camel to upcase snake case

Tags: replace, emacs, uppercase

I spent 3 hours trying to figure out to modify a string at point to different cases, e.g. `isFailedUpgrade` to `IS_FAILED_UPGRADE`.

I got to the point where i can get the string at point to a var `text` but has no idea how to update a string `text` to the desired case.

```
(defun change-case ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((bounds (if (use-region-p)
                     (cons (region-beginning) (region-end))
                   (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))
         (text   (buffer-substring-no-properties (car bounds) (cdr bounds))))
    (when bounds
      (delete-region (car bounds) (cdr bounds))
      (insert (change-case-helper text)))))

# the following code is rubbish 
(defun change-case-helper (text)
  (let ((output ""))
    (dotimes (i (length text))
      (concat output (char-to-string (aref text i))))
    output))
```

Since i am on the journey to learn a little emacs function myself, i prefer to write this function myself instead of use an existing magical function.

---

ok after another 2 hours, i think i've figured it out:

```
(defun change-case ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((bounds (if (use-region-p)
                     (cons (region-beginning) (region-end))
                   (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)))
         (text   (buffer-substring-no-properties (car bounds) (cdr bounds))))
    (when bounds
      (delete-region (car bounds) (cdr bounds))
      (insert (change-case-helper text)))))

(defun change-case-helper (text)
  (when (and text (> (length text) 0))
    (let ((first-char (string-to-char (substring text 0 1)))
          (rest-str (substring text 1)))
      (concat (if (upcasep first-char) (string ?_ first-char) (string (upcase first-char)))
              (change-case-helper rest-str))))
  )

(defun upcasep (c) (and (= ?w (char-syntax c)) (= c (upcase c))))
```

still feel this is pretty awkward, please comment let me know if there is a better way of writing this function.

Comment: One question per question, please. (I removed your follow-up question, which anyway encouraged opinion-based answers.)

Comment: @drew thanks for editing my question. I wonder what's your opinion on which is the more idiomatic style of writing elisp functions.

Comment: I have no opinion on that; sorry. I suggest you ask something like that on a discussion site, such as Reddit.

Comment: check out `s.el` which has functions you could learn from.  You could use a higher order function, taking a predicate to split the words, then join by another -- see `s-split-words` for their version

Comment: @Rorschach great, yes, higher order string functions are the thing i am missing here.